# how can i use generic to PdfPcells

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I'm using iTextSharp to generate table and  I want to make a Generic of Pdfcells instead of adding manually

```
PdfPCell HeadCell0 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("FullName", Htitle));
HeadCell0.BackgroundColor = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
PdfPCell HeadCell1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Username", Htitle));
HeadCell1.BackgroundColor = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
PdfPCell HeadCell2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Email", Htitle));
HeadCell2.BackgroundColor = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
PdfPCell HeadCell3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Department", Htitle));
HeadCell3.BackgroundColor = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
PdfPCell HeadCell4 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("AddedBy", Htitle));
HeadCell4.BackgroundColor = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
PdfPCell HeadCell5 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Account Type", Htitle));
HeadCell5.BackgroundColor = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
```

Comment: Is [PdfPTable.getDefaultCell()](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html#getDefaultCell%28%29) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If @Alexis Pigeon's comment isn't what you're looking for then how about a wrapper function?

```
public static PdfPCell MakeHeader(string text, iTextSharp.text.Font Htitle) {
    PdfPCell HeadCell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(text, Htitle));
    HeadCell.BackgroundColor = iTextSharp.text.Color.LIGHT_GRAY;

    return HeadCell;
}

PdfPCell HeadCell0 = MakeHeader("FullName", Htitle);
```

Comment: thanks a lot , my idea is about to pass parameter to method that make for loop and generate the object if got my idea  but really helpful method :)